# Monitor block to handle receiver value too small errors

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

If I want to handle scenarios where a receiver variable is smaller than the required size in a monitor block, I could write something like this:

```
D Tgttoosmall     C                   103 
D Result          S             11  2 
D Source          S             15  2
/Free
Monitor;
Result = Source;
On-error Tgttoosmall;
...
// Process exception here
...   
Endmon; 
/End-free
```

But I want to know if this is the best practice?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I agree. It looks good. Your code in the block is very small and you're trapping a very specific error.  Also, you're using a constant for the error code to make everything more readable.

Comment: I have seen in other programs in my company where no error code has been mentioned on the ON-ERROR making it a generic handler. Do you think this is a good thing to do?

Comment: More often than not I don't use a specific code with On-Error.  I often ask myself, "Do I only want to trap this one specific error, or any possible error that could happen?"  If it's the latter, it's usually the combination of the two if I handle the errors differently.

Comment: So the need to add the monitor blocks comes as there are few database fields whose size is being increased. Wherever the modified variables are being assigned to smaller receivers in programs, I need to include a Monitor block to handle any receiver too small errors that might come up.. So i am trapping only this error as if any other errors come up, they should be captured and highlighted..

Comment: And once `highlighted`, then what? Are programs simply going to run until some future unknown times as each potential error shows up?

Comment: If some other error is thrown up apart from the `receiver too small one`, the root cause would have to be found out and a permanent fix applied for that. in my recovery plan, the on-error assigns a *HIVAL to the receiver field.. if a generic On-error statement is used, the receiver gets assigned a  *HIVAL whatever the exception... which might be undesirable as the only change is that field sizes are being enlarged. Thoughts on this please.

Answer (score 0):

During the development and testing it is better to have all the exceptions highlighted. To control the production environment from the known possibilities, monitoring the unknown errors is not a good practice. A thorough unit testing is better than oops!